# My Nexus4 is stuck on the start up screen after lollypop update

Tags: nexus-4, screen, 5.0-lollipop

I did updated my nexus 4 to lollipop day before yesterday. It said is it installed and requires a reboot.. I did the reboot and now the screen is stuck at the bouncing balls of Google start up. What do i do? Thanks

Comment: This can take absolutely ages - Give it time. In fact, it should be finished by now? :)

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?